# GHDL: no function declarations for operator "and"

Tags: vhdl, logical-operators, ghdl

Here is my stripped example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity queue is
    port(
        reset: in std_logic;
        input_ready: out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture reference of queue is
    signal queue_size: unsigned(15 downto 0);
begin
    process
    begin
            input_ready <= (reset = '0') and (queue_size < 1024);
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Where this line:

```
input_ready <= (reset = '0') and (queue_size < 1024);
```

produces

```
no function declarations for operator "and"
ghdl: compilation error
```

when running

```
ghdl -a queue.vhdl
```

with `GHDL 0.32rc1 (20141104) [Dunoon edition]` on Arch Linux.

According to [VHDL operators](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/operator.html) both comparisons return boolean and there is `and` definition for two booleans. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two sub expressions `(reset = '0')` and `(queue_size < 1024)` return a boolean value. The `and` operator also returns a boolean result, which you are trying to assign to a std_logic output.

The solution:

```
input_ready <= '1' when (reset = '0') and (queue_size < 1024) else '0';
```

Note: This line needs no surrounding process.

Comment: And I thought I can avoid being affected by C background... VHDL resolves overloads by return type as well, doesn't it?

Comment: @Dadam: Overload by return type is exactly the issue, and yes VHDL does.

Comment: You could also note the parentheses in Paebbels solution are redundant. Relational operators ("=") are higher priority than logical operators ("and"). IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.2 Operators, 9.2.1 General.